# Is the flint used in disposable lighters toxic?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, metal, toxicity, alloy

Especially the sparks that result when using them. I heard this from a friend and can't seem to find an answer on Google.

Answer (score 4):

The "flint" in disposable lighters is made of pyrophoric alloy called "[ferrocerium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrocerium)", which consists of approx. 50% cerium, 25% lanthanum and 20% iron; the remaining 5% is magnesium, neodymium and praseodymium. Exact composition may vary depending on the manufacturer.

If you rub such an alloy on a rough surface, tiny metal particles are formed, which are instantly ignited and produce metal oxides. Neither of the expected products are particularly toxic: lanthanoid oxides, particularly $\ce{CeO2}$ and $\ce{La2O3}$, are not toxic and can only cause *mild irritation when swallowed*, and iron oxide $\ce{Fe3O4}$ is basically rust.

To sum it up, unless you are allergic to transition metals (which people usually discover very early), I cannot think of any health hazards coming from the "flint" or the sparks.